# Get list of JUnit test Classes from the source code context in Java

Tags: java, reflection, junit

In order to generate some test documentation, I would like to get a list of JUnit test classes in the project. Assume, we have the following project structure.

```
project/
  src/
    Main.java
  test/
    XTest.java
    YTest.java
```

The Main.java file should be able to read all the test classes (i.e. XTest and YTest) in order to extract all the test methods. 
The usual suspects like `Package.getPackage()` do not seem to work on test classes, but only on the actual source code.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Have you considered parsing the surefire (or whatever test executor) reports?

Comment: @beresfordt We already do that to persist the test results. In addition, we also would like to document the actual test code which has been extended and documented by custom annotations. The goal now is to extract these annotations from the test methods and export them to Confluence. So it is really necessary to actually read the test classes using reflection.

Comment: Then you're going to need to invoke Main in such a way that the test classes are on its classpath. Will add an answer with details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You for Main to access the classes XTest and YTest those classes will need to be on its classpath when it executes.

Assuming the following post compilation directory structure:

```
project/
  src/
    Main.java
  test/
    XTest.java
    YTest.java
  target/
    classes/
      Main.class
    test-classes/
      XTest.class
      YTest.class
```

The `main` method of `Main` could be executed like so

```
java -classpath target/classes/:target/test-classes/ Main
```

At which point it would have access to the test classes reflectively

It might however be easier to just whack Main into /test and explicitly tell your test executor to run it as part of its test execution